# Assembler memory offsets and segments

Tags: assembly, x86

So, here we refer to this assembly code as an example:

```
.data
        hello_world db 9
end

.code
main      proc
          mov  eax, 2
          lea  ebx, hello_world
main      endp
end
```

Now in an article about assembly I read that, an assembler does the following:

> Saves memory offsets as offsets relative to their corresponding segment

> Replaces the *offsets* and *segments* by a placeholder serving as a relocatable address for the linker

Now, for the first statement what I understand is that:

```
lea ebx, hello_world
```

will be replaced by:

```
lea ebx, ds:[00]
```

is that right?

For the second statement (considering my first statement is right), I don't really understand. The assembler already replaced the memory offset by an offset relative to its segment, so what does the assembler do with the placeholder for offsets?

Does it just mark the offset it as relocatable in the `.obj` file in some way, or does it do something else?

Finally, I don't understand the *placeholder* for *segments*, is it something that happens upon writing this?

```
.data
    hello db 1
ends

.code
main     proc
         lea      eax, data ;copy address of data segment in eax
main     endp
end
```

, or is it something else?

I hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: References to "segment" and "offset" usually refer to 16-bit x86 assembly.  For 32-bit as you have, although technically the concepts still exist, all mainstream OSes provide a flat memory space to applications so you only ever really have offsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the definition of memory variable `hello_world` is the first statement in segment `.data`, then its offset is 0 at **assembly time** and you can see in listing that loading it to `ebx` is assembled to

```
00000000: 8D1D[00000000]     lea ebx, hello_world
```

Brackets `[]` in the listing signalize that the address `00000000` is relocatable and it is marked so in the object file `.obj`.
The loader will assign a different offset for the `.data` segment, say `0x00402000`, at **run time**. Then it has to increase (relocate) the displacement field in the instruction body by the new virtual address. It will be increased by the difference between the allocated `.data` address (`0x00402000`) and the `.data` address assumed by assembler (`0x00000000`).
CPU (and you in debugger) will see

```
00401000: 8D1D[00204000]     lea ebx, hello_world
```

The relocated double word is not just a placeholder, it is regular field of the instruction `lea` which is being updated when the program is loaded to memory.